# High SNR FM demodulation

Tags: rf, audio, analog, frequency-modulation, demodulation

So I need to demodulate the FM signal from a sensor with highest SNR possible, at least 70-75 dB. IF is 10.7 MHz, max. deviation is 200 kHz but I can change those values if needed. Baseband signal frequency range is 60-5000 Hz. There is a space constraint: PCB should not be larger than 18x40 mm. It also would be nice if the circuit could be powered from a 3.3-5V source.

Quadrature detectors I find have SNR of <60 dB which is insufficient. The only solution I found is NJW2311V but I can't find it for sale. Maybe there are other options?

Comment: What are you asking? Right now, it reads like a "design this circuit for me" question, which is off-topic.

Comment: @Hearth I'm asking about demodulator topologies and/or ICs that can do the job.

Comment: That sounds like a shopping question ("what part should I use"), which is also off-topic.

Comment: The SNR you can get out is foremost a function of the signal you put in; at room temperature, without absurd powers involved, 75 dB is um... hard. I think you should start with a more in-depth discussion of what you're building.

Comment: given TimeJitter = Vnoise / Slewrate, what is your system design?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm playing with a capacitive microphone. The microphone capsule modulates a Seiler oscillator running at 42 MHz and then mixed with crystal LO and demodulated. I fed the signal from an oscillator to the SDR receiver and its noise is below receiver's own noise level.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf see above

Comment: Since *your* baseband bandwidth is somewhat narrower than the usual FM receiver spec, you could gain some dB SNR here. Space constraint suggests a PLL demodulator.

Comment: You'll likely want to lookup FM demodulation with PLL

Comment: @cyrtex ah, interesting! so, exactly as glen and sstobbe recommend, a PLL would be the demodulator of choice, and your problem very much suggests you want to carefully design the loop filter. PLL ICs are pretty common; designing the loop filter will be the more challenging part. Alternatively, if SDR works for you, most ARM Cortex-M4F MCUs would be fast enough to digitize and deal with something at >= 400 kS/s.

Comment: @MarcusMüller could you please suggest me one? I looked for PLL ICs before and found only TLC2933 but its VCO jitter is 100 ps which looks quite high to me

Comment: your phase noise will be limited by your loop filter and the quality of VCO, so not inherently through your PLL IC. There's a lot PLL ICs, and 100 ps is an RMS value; typically, phase noise is pretty f²-decreasing, so this might not be as dramatic as you think.